# Is Reentrancy Check compulsory while inilaizing the initializeGenesisBlock function?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-classic, genesis

I have one doubt while initializing a Genesis Block function in solidity smart contract

Question = Is Reentracy Check compulsory while inilaizing the initializeGenesisBlock function ?

```
   function initializeGenesisBlock(
    ExchangeData.State storage S,
    address _Addr,
    bytes32 _genesisMerkleRoot,
    bytes32 _genesisMerkleAssetRoot,
    bytes32 _domainSeparator
    )
    public
{
    require(address(0) != _Addr, "INVALID_ADDRESS");
    require(_genesisMerkleRoot != 0, "INVALID_GENESIS_MERKLE_ROOT");
    require(_genesisMerkleAssetRoot != 0, "INVALID_GENESIS_MERKLE_ASSET_ROOT");


  ................
  ...............
................
```

}

Is the Above function have correct check or it should have a Reeentracy Check by using the ReeentracyGuard.sol import in this Function

Please Clear my this doubt

Thank You

Comment: Why do you need a reentrancy check for your function? 
https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/attacks/reentrancy/
Check this out on reentrancy.